# Jost function in Scattering Theory

Tags: scattering, complex-numbers, s-matrix-theory

I have a doubt about the behaviour of the Jost function $f_l(p)$. The chapter 12 of the book of Scattering Theory of John R. Taylor shows that the eigenvalues of the $\hat{S}$ matrix may be given as the ratio
$$s_l(p) = \frac{f_l(p)^*}{f_l(p)}.$$ It is also said that the Jost function is real on the imaginary axis, since
$$f(p)=[f(-p^*)]^*.$$ Thus, $f_l(p)$ should be real as $p\rightarrow\,0\,$ from the positive imaginary axis, but so the $\lim_{p\rightarrow0}
s_l(p)=1$ and no scattering would happen at zero energy limit (since the scattering amplitude is given by $F_l(p)=\frac{s_l(p)-1}{2\,i\,p}$), what does not seem reasonable.

Comment: $s(p)\to 1$ does not imply that $\frac{s(p)-1}{p}\to0$. Consider e.g. $s(p)=\mathrm e^p$.

Comment: Thanks  AccidentalFourierTransform , I was missing the $p$ in the denominator

Answer (score 1):

Probably my doubt was solved from the comment of " AccidentalFourierTransform" . The scattering amplitude goes to zero just if the scattering eigenvalue goes to 1 as a power greater than p. If
$\lim_{p\rightarrow\,0}\,s_l(p)= 1 +i\,b\,p $ where $b$ is a constant, then the scattering amplitude does not go to zero.